# In VB Script get a number after a word and put into a cell on xls file

Tags: vbscript

Can anybody help and tell me how i can write something in VBscript to get anything that came after a word in a txt file and put it into a cell of a xls file?

The name of txt file is state.txt and the content is this:

PowerState = 13

I want to get the number 13 (or what number is after the "="), from a txt file and put it into B1 cell of a xls file named power.xls.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you have. We'll go from there.

Answer (score 1):

I just went Data - Import External Data - Import Data. Told it to break on = and skip column 1. So 13 got put into B1. It can be refreshed at any time.

Comment: Haha. You could just open Excel and type `13` into B1, too, but I think he wants a VBScript. =)